# jquery autocomplete show all list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show all data whatever I input.
for example:

```
data = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]      
$( "#tag_field" ).autocomplete({
   source: data
});
```

when I input "d", it suggest me all data. just show all data whatever I input.
How can I do that?

Comment: so, if you input `a` you want it to filter to only `aaa`, but if there are no matches then you want to show everything?

Comment: no, If I input "a" it show all data, if I input "b" it show all, I want It always show all. because the data is filter by AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be a solution:

```js
data = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
$( "#tag_field" ).autocomplete({
  source: data,
  response: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.content.splice(0,ui.content.length);
    $.each(data,function(i,n){
      ui.content.push({label:n, value:n});
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<input id="tag_field" type="text">
```

Comment: this works very nice, but I want even I input "a" it show "aaa" , "bbb", "ccc",  I want It just always show all data, because the data is filter by AJAX.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question but I think there are better approaches for what are you trying. You can display the list on focus or something similar instead of use autocomplete.